# Having trouble implementing onClickListener for a custom ListAdapter Listview

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, custom-adapter

I am having trouble implementing `onItemClick` for my `ListView` . I need to open a new activity on clicking the item in my `ListView` and pass the title/genre/rating/release year data to this new activity. I would also like to know how can I pass the thumbnail image of the clicked Item in `ListView` and display it in a new activity.

CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // rating
        rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Main2Activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = Main2Activity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(service_list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                //new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send whole object movieItem and position of item click then In next activity you can extract them like this.

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
            {
                intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),NextActivity.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", movielist);
intent.putExtra("IntKey",p3);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Passing whole list can allow you to change your movie in second activity

Comment: does this pass the whole data from that clicked List to new Activity ?

Comment: It will send whole arraylist of movie and clicked position in listview to the second activity.Using this you can extract the title and other data of movielist at clicked position in second activity

Comment: how can i display the Bitmap image in second activity here ?

Comment: You can get image url in second activity using movie object.

Comment: To get bitmap already loaded , you have to pass it as parcelable through intent.

Comment: and then convert the url to image ?

Comment: To get bitmap already loaded , you have to pass it as parcelable through intent.

Comment: I tried passing it as a parcelable, but app keeps crashing.

Comment: No. I have tested ..worked correctly.   Check it again

Comment: It did not work for me, so i used a image loading library. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the individual items of the model calls as Extras to an intent, or you can make the model class implement the Serializable interface and just add the whole object to the intent manually :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Movie movie = (Movie) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mName", movie.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("mRating", movie.getRating());
            intent.putExtra("mGenre", movie.getGenre());
            intent.putExtra("mYear". movie.getYear());

            //Get the Bitmap object from the NetworkImageView
            Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)((NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            //Can be added directly as an Extra, as Bitmap implements Parcelable
            intent.putExtra("mImage", bm);

            //OR make Moview implement Serializable and do this :
            //intent.putExtra("clickedObject", movie);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In the receiving activity, you can use getExtras() to get the values :

```
Bitmap bm = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("mImage");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: what about the Image i use in ListView(first activity). I wanted to pass and display the image in new activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to implement it now and leave a reply :)

Comment: `Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)((NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            //Can be added directly as an Extra, as Bitmap implements Parcelable
            intent.putExtra("mImage", bm);`

Can you please explain this part? am not aware of how bitmap images work and how can i fetch and display it in second activity.

Comment: A bitmap object represents the image that you downloaded from the URL. If you have an ImageView in your receiving activity, you can load it with the Bitmap from the first activity. Edited my answer to show this.

Comment: when i click on the List item, instead of opening the new activity .. app just terminates.

Comment: `Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)((NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
intent.putExtra("mImage", bm);`

After adding this code in first activity, when i click on the list item, app just closes down without showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine, after i changed the code with the help of people who answered to this question.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Movie movie = (Movie) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mName", movie.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("mRating", movie.getRating());
            intent.putExtra("mGenre", movie.getGenre());
            intent.putExtra("mYear", movie.getYear());
            intent.putExtra("mServiceImage",movie.getThumbnailUrl());
            //OR make Moview implement Serializable and do this :
            //intent.putExtra("clickedObject", movie);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In the final activity i use Android-Universal-Image-Loader to load the image  from the url i passed from first activity.

```
  String mName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mServiceImage");
  imageLoader.displayImage(mName, imageView);
```